# Tabela com evento drag and drop não funciona em mobile

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Tenho uma página que o usuário de ter a liberdade de ordenar tabela, e este evento drag and drop no computador funciona perfeitamente, mas em tablets, mobiles não funciona, **o que se deve fazer para o perfeito funcionamentos deste evento em dispositivos mobile ?**

Em minha tabela inseri um id

```
<tbody id="sortable" style="cursor:pointer">
```

e também nesta linha o script pega a linha com os valores

```
<td class="taskSingleInLine" id="task@(Model.LoteList.ElementAt(i).NumeroLote)" data-taskid="@(Model.Genero.ElementAt(i).GeneroId)-@(i+1)">
```

Segue abaixo código Javscript/Ajax e o html

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#sortable").sortable({
            update: function (event, ui) {
                var itemIds = "";
                $("#sortable").find(".taskSingleInLine").each(function () {
                    var itemId = $(this).attr("data-taskid");
                    itemIds = itemIds + itemId + ",";
                });
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("UpdateItem", "Lotes")',
                    data: { itemIds: itemIds },
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function (data) {
                        location.reload();
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Html - ASP.NET MVC**

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Lote.NumeroLote)
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody id="sortable" style="cursor:pointer">

            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.LoteList.Count(); i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td class="taskSingleInLine" id="task@(Model.LoteList.ElementAt(i).NumeroLote)" data-taskid="@(Model.Genero.ElementAt(i).GeneroId)-@(i+1)">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.LoteList.ElementAt(i).NumeroLote)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Segundo esse tópico no Github https://github.com/metafizzy/packery/issues/336 o jquery ui não suporta toque na tela. Você pode usar como solução isso aqui. http://touchpunch.furf.com/

Comment: @NetinhoSantos o http://touchpunch.furf.com/ não funciona com tabelas.